# D5100 auto Lv from HDMI splitter/Switch

Tags: live-view

I am new to forums and, although I have had my Nikon D5100 for some time and feel I know my way around it pretty well, there is a feature that eludes my knowledge.

I am about to embark on some live streaming DJ podcasts and have a go pro hero 4 and me beloved D5100.  While I know that the Lv timer is there to protect the camera and the sensor my D5100 has an annoying habit of switching of Lv when I change camera through the splitter to my gopro and I have to manually switch Lv back on when I go back to the Nikon.

Is there anyway I can have the splitter turn Lv back on via HDMI control or is it something I would have to live with.  Kindest regards and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway I can have the splitter turn Lv back on via HDMI control or is it something I would have to live with?

Your only option (other than just live with it) is to get a better HDMI switch. Internally, your switch disconnects an input from the output when it switches to the other input. Thus, the device connected to the first input (such as your D5100) thinks it has been unplugged from the output device. And electrically, it has been.

A better HDMI switch will still maintain "dummy" electrical connections and signals, so that the input devices still think they are connected to the output device, and thus won't change their output modes, turn off Live View, etc.